# How can I get the user's location in JS and then pass the response to the Google map as coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, typeerror

I am trying to get the users location in JS using geolocation successfully and the 2 log statements print out the co-ordinates. How do I pass in the startPos into the Google map function?

Error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined

at initMap (dashboard.js:20)

Thanks!

Code:

```
var startPos;

window.onload = function() {
    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        startPos = position;
        //document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
        console.log(startPos.coords.latitude);
        //document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
        console.log(startPos.coords.longitude);
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
    return startPos;

    // Initialize and add the map

};
function initMap() {
    // The location of user

    var lat = startPos.coords.latitude;
    var long = startPos.coords.longitude;

    const userLocation = { lat: lat, lng: long };
    // The map, centered at Uluru
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: userLocation,
    });
    // The marker, positioned at Uluru
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userLocation,
        map: map,
    });
}
```

initMap(startPos);

Answer (score 0):

The reason that initMap is accessing an undefined startPos, is that it is being executed *before* the onload event has started, and *before* the geoSuccess callback has been called by the arrival of the location data.

So it should look more like:

```
var startPos;

window.onload = function() {
    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        startPos = position;
        //document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
        console.log(startPos.coords.latitude);
        //document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
        console.log(startPos.coords.longitude);

        initMap(); // Call it here!
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
};
function initMap() {
    // The location of user

    var lat = startPos.coords.latitude;
    var long = startPos.coords.longitude;

    const userLocation = { lat: lat, lng: long };
    // The map, centered at Uluru
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: userLocation,
    });
    // The marker, positioned at Uluru
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userLocation,
        map: map,
    });
}
```